# Modify base T4 Template pernamently

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, t4

What I want to do:
Each time I add a  ADO.NET Entity Data Model (EF Designer from database) item to my project I want generated code .Context to contain overload of the default constructor that takes a connection string.

Question:
Is it possible to modify base T4 Template for Entity Framework permanently in my Visual Studio instance?

I do it manually each time I add new model and it doesn't take too much effort but I would like to have it automatically.

Comment: Have you tried making a partial class instead?